# Asp.net com GitHub

Tags: c#, asp.net, github

tenho algum tempo de experiência com versionamento GITHUB com java, sempre funcionou com eficiência entre equipes. Estou com um projeto ASP.NET baseado em WebForms, e estou tentando versionar com GITHUB. Versionei o projeto com o meu usuário, e quando outro membro da equipa clona o projeto do repositório e tenta alterar os arquivos funciona normalmente, porém, ao tentar programar um evento de um botão de qualquer WebForm, não é possível criar o evento, ou dando um duplo clique sobre o botão, ou então, através da aba events, não é possível criar o evento. O estranho é o outro usuário consegue alterar qualquer arquivo, tanto .aspx quanto aspx.cs, o problema é apenas na criação de eventos.

Alguém tem alguma dica?

Obrigado

Comment: Dica: asp.net puro é obsoleto, mudem para asp.net mvc. Posso parecer bruto ao dizer isso, mas vocês vão ganhar em produtividade e se libertar do arrasta e clica do VS.

Comment: Você deve notar que em `asp.net` com `WebForms` existem fisicamente três arquivos, um **aspx**, **aspx.cs** e **aspx.resx**. Um evento por exemplo, requer alterar dois arquivos, se não for feito o *checkout* de ambos (aspx e aspx.cs) não irá funcionar. Não sei como funciona o `Git` com projetos `WebForms` mas pode ser que tenha de fazer o *checkout* manual dos arquivos, verifique e avise ainda estiver com problema

Comment: Só uma correção, infelizmente estou com um projeto webforms aberto aqui,os três arquivos são: `.aspx`, `aspx.cs` e `.aspx.designer.cs`. Sendo que o último é auto-gerado ao manipular o primeiro. E aí talvez seja a causa do problema, se o versionamento não esteja incluindo eles.

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou, os três arquivos estão sendo clonados normalmente.